# Syntax highlighting not working vim-polyglot

Tags: macvim

So I've installed http://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-polyglot as per those instructions (it shows up with `:ListPlugins` ), but it's not highlighting any of my code.

I realise that's not a lot to go on, but is there any configuration work? Or should it all be automatic?

I do see yellow and blue tag indicators though - is it possible that terminal theming breaks the syntax highlighting?

Does anyone have any experience or would know why? Thanks. :)

Comment: Did you tried `:set hl ` ?

Comment: If I do that I get:

`highlight=8:SpecialKey,@:NonText,d:Directory,e:ErrorMsg,i:IncSearch,l:Search,m:MoreMsg,M:ModeMsg,n:LineNr,r:Question,s:StatusLi
ne,S:StatusLineNC,c:VertSplit,t:Title,v:Visual,V:VisualNOS,w:WarningMsg,W:WildMenu,f:Folded,F:FoldColumn,A:DiffAdd,C:DiffChange,D
:DiffDelete,T:DiffText,>:SignColumn,-:Conceal,B:SpellBad,P:SpellCap,R:SpellRare,L:SpellLocal,+:Pmenu,=:PmenuSel,x:PmenuSbar,X:Pme
nuThumb,*:TabLine,#:TabLineSel,_:TabLineFill,!:CursorColumn,.:CursorLine,o:ColorColumn`

Comment: This happened for us in vi editor. May be, you cab set compatible to nocomaptible or vice versa to see the effect.

Comment: The output shows that your vim has applied colorscheme., but the terminal may have a problem. Did you tried `set t_Co=256` in your vimrc file. This might show ttesut.

Comment: Tried it: No effect. :(

Comment: What is the output of `echo $TERM`?

Comment: `xterm-256color`

Comment: I don't know if it matters but I use iTerm2 & ZSH.

Comment: I've used polyglot in the past, and I never got any problem. Do you have `syntax on` ?

Comment: @nobe4 where do you put that setting? or is it a terminal command?

Comment: Usually at the start of your vimrc.

Comment: @nobe4 You sir are a genius! If you put that as the answer I'll accept it...

Is there a reference to that in 'getting started' or the docs??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to use the syntax highlighting in vim you must put the following line on your vimrc:

```
syntax on
```

Depending on your preferences/plugin manager (if any), it may want to put it at the start of your vimrc.

Have a look at :

- `:h usr_06.txt`
- `:h syntax`

---

**PS:** to sort my vim options, I use the `:options` command and sort using the existing groups.

Comment: TIL: there is an useful command named `:options`.